# .htaccess causing errors, error log empty

Tags: php, apache, http, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file here that is from open source bitcoin exchange written in php called wlox.

Unfortunately its causing a server 500 error and the error logs are empty.
This is what the file looks like.

If anybody knows what is wrong in this file, and can help me correct it that'd be great

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apii/
RewriteRule ^([a-z/-]*)$ index.php?endpoint=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You sure your `RewriteBase` is really `apii` and not `api`?...

Comment: @War10ck yes i am.

Comment: _"Unfortunately its causing a server 500 error and the error logs are empty."_ - then you're either not checking the right files/locations, or you haven't got the webserver properly configured to log errors. Go check.

Comment: @CBroe i got rid of the first line of the .htaccess and it works fine.

Comment: Syntax locks ok at a glance. Check if mod_headers is enabled, and if `AllowOverride` includes `FileInfo` - that is necessary for you to be able to use the `Header` directive inside .htaccess.

Comment: Check the error log inside `/var/log/`. Errors will show up there as well.